# probl in using functions in c

Tags: c, function

I want to display an integer output (`function1`) and a float output (`function2`).

`function1`: input an integer number, if the number is odd display odd, else display even.

`function2`: input two float numbers, multiply them by 4 and add them and display the answer.

Whats wrong with this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

function1(int a)
{ 
  if(a%2!=0)
  {printf("odd number");}
  else
  {printf("even number");}

  return a;
}

function2(float b, float c)
{
  float d;
  b=b*4;
  c=c*4;
  d=b+c;

  return d;
}

main()
{
  float p,q;
  int r;

  printf("Input 2 float numbers\n");
  scanf("%f %f",&p,&q);
  printf("Input a integer number\n");
  scanf("%d",&r);
  printf("%f\n",function2());
  printf(" : %d\n",function1());

  return 0;      
}
```

Comment: Please format/indent your code first.. Just like in the samples in your C textbook. And please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.)

Comment: Well, what's wrong with it, we don't know, please edit your question and state clearly 1. yout input, 2. the actual output, 3. the expected output.

Comment: Does the program returns a compilation error or an incorrect result? You should be more specific when you asking "Whats wrong with this?".

Comment: @HenriqueMoisés I can't get the result! Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Ok, no prob :) 
So I'm assuming you have a compilation error. Did you followed the link provided by @Jack Miller. I think he answered correctly.

Comment: nope I didnt get that! what is return type?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shoud be

```
 int function1(int a)
 float function2(float b, float c)
```

also

```
 main(){
 float p,q;
 int r;
 printf("Input 2 float numbers\n");
 scanf("%f %f",&p,&q);
 printf("Input a integer number\n");
 scanf("%d",&r);
 printf("%f\n",function2(p,q));
 printf(" : %d\n",function1(r));
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions in c require a return type:

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
  body of the function
}
```

if you are outputting an int do:

```
    int function( int a ) {
    return a;
}
```

see : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_functions.htm

for more help

Comment: That's a comment, not answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get that! what is return type?

Comment: Return Type − A function may return a value. The return_type is the data type of the value the function returns. Some functions perform the desired operations without returning a value. In this case, the return_type is the keyword void.

Comment: Read the given link to learn about functions and return types